# Wrapping my head around specific use of jQuery's .trigger event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to go through and document a plugin so I can understand how it works and I've come across a function that uses .trigger in a way that I can't understand. From what I think I know, .trigger is usually used to call custom events. Here is this use case of trigger in the plugin:

```
$( this ).trigger( "beforecreate." + pluginName )
[ pluginName ]( "_init" )
[ pluginName ]( "_addNextPrev" )
.trigger( "create." + pluginName );
```

Can anyone explain to me what this is saying? The syntax is different from what is in the jQuery documentation so I'm assuming that it's some kind of shorthand or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are confused about the `[...]` and not about `.trigger`. In JavaScript there are two ways to access object properties: dot notation (`obj.someProp`) and bracket notation (`obj['someProp']`).
You have to use bracket notation if the property name is not a valid identifier (e.g. if it contains spaces) or you have the property name in a variable, which is the case here.

Lets assume that

```
var pluginName = 'foo';
```

then the code above is equivalent to:

```
$( this )
  .trigger( "beforecreate." + pluginName )
  .foo( "_init" )
  .foo( "_addNextPrev" )
  .trigger( "create." + pluginName );
```

Here is another (made up) example. Both of these are equivalent:

```
$(this).find('.foo');
$(this)['find']('.foo');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was confused about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:

```
//  This is triggering the "beforecreate" EVENT on the plugin
$( this ).trigger( "beforecreate." + pluginName )
//  is calling the initialize event within the class
[ pluginName ]( "_init" )
//  i assume is calling another method in the class, probably to set specific html to the element being modded
[ pluginName ]( "_addNextPrev" )
//  Now that everything has been setup and the element has been "Created" into the plugin,
//    the coder is now triggering the plugin upon that element
.trigger( "create." + pluginName );
```

Comment: Thanks for documenting that for me. I wasn't familiar with bracket notation so that's why I didn't know how those methods were being called. The only thing that still doesn't make sense to me is actually the .trigger. There aren't "beforecreate" or "create" events anywhere. Maybe this is for something the author plans to add later?

Comment: perhaps, does the plugin work with any jquery-mobile widgets? if so, jquery mobile, before its latest update included events like "beforecreate"

Comment: I just read this short article by Chris Coyier:
http://css-tricks.com/custom-events-are-pretty-cool/

I didn't realize that this was technique to extend the code. It totally makes sense that this would be used to extend itself to other things like jquery-mobile widgets or whatever you wanted to use it with. Thanks again!